# Mapping of multipart file to cucumber expression

Tags: spring-boot, cucumber, integration-testing, cucumber-java

I want to map multipart file to cucumber expression

for example:

```
When("Name {string}")
```

same way how can I do that for multipart file?

I tried
when(" file: {} ")
but getting error can not cast anonymous to multipart

Answer (score 0):

You'd use a [custom parameter type](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/tree/main/cucumber-java#parameter-type). For example:

```java
public class StepDefinitions {

    @ParameterType("([0-9]{4})-([0-9]{2})-([0-9]{2})")
    public LocalDate iso8601Date(String year, String month, String day) {
        return LocalDate.of(Integer.parseInt(year), Integer.parseInt(month), Integer.parseInt(day));
    }

    @Given("today is {iso8601Date}")
    public void today_is(LocalDate date) {

    }
}
```

In the method annotated with `@ParameterType` you'd transform the capture groups from the Regex into an object with the type you want. This is then passed to your step definition.